# Redirecting to the previous screen inside of a Dialog

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, dialog

I have a custom `Dialog` with 4 linked screens(which come one by one on click of a `Continue` button) in my ASP.Net MVC application. On the 2nd screen, the user has an option to click a button which re-directs him to a entirely different screen(but inside the `Dialog`). Here there is a `Save` button. I want the user to go back to the 2nd screen when the `Save` is done but the `Dialog` is getting closed(redirecting to the landing page from where the `Dialog` was thrown initially. I'm doing a  `return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());` on click of the `Save` button but it clearly doesn't work the way I want it to.

How can I make the user stay on the `Dialog`? Can you please help me with the fix?

Comment: What does 'button doesn't work' mean? Nothing happens? It redirects to the wrong page? What the value of UrlReferrer?

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/470005/sergey-berezovskiy I meant it closes the Dialog and redirects to the landing page from which the Dialog was initially opened

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/470005/sergey-berezovskiy the value of UrlReferrer is my Controller's Index method(this is from where the Dialog was initially thrown)

Comment: Looks like the Save button is posting the form. You have to use ajax to avoid the form post and navigate away from the page.  `return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());` is sending you to a new page and surely you will loose this page's data.